# Objective C: Show Nav and Tab Bar

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I am buiding an app with an UIWebView, a UITabBar, and multiple other views, each one for a Tab.
I want to show the Nav bar, Tab bar and the view in one go. When I type this:

```
    -(BOOL) (UIApplication *) application ApplicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDIctionary *) launchOptions {
[_window addSubView: tabController.view];
[_window addSubView: navController.view];
[self._window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

I get everything I want, but i cannot click the Tab Bar (I see it, it lods all right). The button I made works in the Nav bar, but I cannot click the Tab Bar tabs.
When I swap them:

```
  -(BOOL) (UIApplication *) application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDIctionary *) launchOptions {
    [_window addSubView: navController.view];
    [_window addSubView: tabController.view];
    [self._window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
    }
```

I get my TabBar, with clickable tabs, but no Nav Bar. I don't even see it.
So, my structure is:

```
-Window:
  -TabBarController:
    -> View1.xib
      -UIWebView
      -UINavigationBar
    -> View3.xib
      -UIWebView
      -UINavigationBar
    -> View3.xib
      -UIWebView
      -UINavigationBar
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `ApplicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` doesn't look right, is this pseudo code?

Comment: Edited, you were right, it had to be: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. And it's no pseudocode, I use Xcode 4, which has new kind of functions, which are built in by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you can't add both nab and tab bar controllers to a window. Usually the structure is:

- Window

  - TabBarController
  - Controller of tab 1

    - NavigationController of tab 1
  - Controller of tab 2

    - NavigationController of tab 2
  - Controller of tab 3

    - NavigationController of tab 3
  - Controller of tab etc.

    - NavigationController of tab etc.

That allows to have different navigation controllers for different tabs. And single tab pane for an application.

It's possible to invert the structure and to have a Navigation Controller on the top of it and tabs somewhere lower. But it's not a normal usage of these components.

I want to mention, that you can add only TabBar's view to window, all other views are handled by controllers.

Comment: Well, I have a kind of different structure. However, When I try to do that what you say:
I have three other views, which are shown automaticly by the Tabbar controller, I didn't code that, but used the TabBar Controller from Xcode. So I chose in the interface builder that for each tab, the TabBar controller shows the .xib matching the tab. However (they are all UIWebViews), when I add Navigation Bars to  each .xib, They don't show up, and only the UIWebView shows. How to do that then?

Comment: So, my structure is:
-Window:
  -TabBarController:
    -> View1.xib
      -UIWebView
      -UINavigationBar
    -> View3.xib
      -UIWebView
      -UINavigationBar
    -> View3.xib
      -UIWebView
      -UINavigationBar

Comment: Now I get what you are saying. Thanks so much! 
The problem was that I did not know I could expand my ViewController pane in Xcode 4. Now I can see how each part of my View is connected, and I can manually reposition them, the way you said. Thanks again!